# Organigrama con html5 y css3

Tags: html5, css3

buenas tengo este código, que es un organigrama

```css
.organigrama * {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.organigrama ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.organigrama li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px 5px 0px 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.organigrama li::before,
.organigrama li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #27629b;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.organigrama li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #27629b;
}

.organigrama li:only-child::before,
.organigrama li:only-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.organigrama li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.organigrama li:first-child::before,
.organigrama li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.organigrama li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #27629b;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.organigrama li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.organigrama ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #27629b;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.organigrama li a {
  border: 1px solid #27629b;
  padding: 1em 0.75em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms;
  transition: all 500ms;
}

.organigrama li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #ddd;
  background-color: rgba(39, 98, 155, 0.7);
  display: inline-block;
}

.organigrama>ul>li>a {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.organigrama>ul>li>ul>li>a {
  width: 15%;
}

.organigrama li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px 5px 0px 5px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<Div id="organigrama" name="organigrama" class="organigrama">
  <ul id="ul1" name="ul1">
    <li>
      <a href="#"><label>Junta Directiva</label></a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><label>Direccion general</br>Carlos maldonado</label></a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><label>Direcion nacional de</br>ventas</br>Alejandro Fuentes</label></a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><label>Gerente de zona</br>Luis Salinas</label></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><label>Direccion de organizacion</br>y procesos</br>Yorbis Centeno</label></a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><label>Gerente de zona</br>Luis Salinas</label></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><label>Direccion administrativa</br>Daisy Marcano</label></a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><label>Gerente de zona</br>Luis Salinas</label></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

lo que deseo es que luis salinas este debajo de los tres sin ser repetido

Comment: Hola Rosibel. ¿Has intentado algo para conseguir lo que pides?  Añade más informacion, siguiendo [ask],.Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b, he intentado varias cosas pero lo que hace es desordenar el organigrama, creo lineas paralelas a las que tengo pero tampoco, ejecuta para que lo veas, ya modifique para que pueda verse

Comment: quieres que quede [asi](https://i.imgur.com/a1HvcMT.png)?

Comment: @lois6b ya el chico de abajo me dio una idea, la estoy realizando, y al parecer me va a funcionar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues simplemente debes jugar con la estructura de listas que tienes, no crear dentro de cada `<li>` un `<ul>` para ingresar el item "Gerente de zona" si no mas bien sacarlo una sola vez a la misma altura de los items principales, así:

```css
.organigrama * {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.organigrama ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.organigrama li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px 5px 0px 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.organigrama li::before,
.organigrama li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #27629b;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.organigrama li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #27629b;
}

.organigrama li:only-child::before,
.organigrama li:only-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.organigrama li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.organigrama li:first-child::before,
.organigrama li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.organigrama li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #27629b;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.organigrama li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.organigrama ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #27629b;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.organigrama li a {
  border: 1px solid #27629b;
  padding: 1em 0.75em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms;
  transition: all 500ms;
}

.organigrama li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #ddd;
  background-color: rgba(39, 98, 155, 0.7);
  display: inline-block;
}

.organigrama>ul>li>a {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.organigrama>ul>li>ul>li>a {
  width: 15%;
}

.organigrama li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px 5px 0px 5px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<Div id="organigrama" name="organigrama" class="organigrama">
  <ul id="ul1" name="ul1">
    <li>
      <a href="#"><label>Junta Directiva</label></a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><label>Direccion general</br>Carlos maldonado</label></a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><label>Direcion nacional de</br>ventas</br>Alejandro Fuentes</label></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><label>Direccion de organizacion</br>y procesos</br>Yorbis Centeno</label></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><label>Direccion administrativa</br>Daisy Marcano</label></a>
            </li>
<li>
                  <a href="#"><label>Gerente de zona</br>Luis Salinas</label></a>
                </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me diste una idea, crearlo en el del medio y crear una linea  que lo una con css